# BeautifulSoup4 find_all strange behavior when called from another object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html doc with a form that I read and pass onto BeautifulSoup to find forms on it as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('form')
```

This returns a result set element as expected, no problem. Now when I do the same thing but this time initiating soup as an object attribute under an object as shown below, I get a None object:

```
class HTML_parser:
    def __init__(self, html_doc):
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    def find_forms(self):
        return self.soup.find_all('form')
```

The code I use to call this class is as follows:

```
html_parser = HTML_parser(content)
html_parser.find_forms()
```

This gives me a None object. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you print whats in variable `content` that you are passing to `HTML_parser()` It might be empty/different string from the string `html_doc` in the first version.

Comment: It's the same thing, self.soup == soup returns True.

Comment: Also, find('form') returns the first form on the html in both cases.

Comment: Strange. You can change the `.find_all()` methods to `.select()` and see if you get the results. Can you share the URL?

Comment: Can you share the html or url? I tried to replicate this problem, and I can't seem to get back None object. For me, it's working just fine.

Comment: I got the html from view-source:https://www.123formbuilder.com/index.php?p=new_user&plan=0&click_from=templates

Comment: I also can't reproduce this. I get results. How are you getting html_doc?

Comment: The select solution is working for me. Thanks @AndrejKesely